# How to do a dynamic destruction?

Tags: c++

I have a vector named EllipseContainer who is full (or will be) of Ellipses and Circles. On this exercise, `Circle` is inheritor of `Ellipse`, so I want to know how to delete them using a dynamic cast.

They have recommended me using this:

```
if (dynamic_cast<Circle*>(Ellipse[i]))
    delete (Circle *)(Ellipse[i]);
```

but I don't really understand what they mean with Ellipse[i], do you have any clues? Have you seen something about dynamic_cast to delete objects?

Comment: If you have inheritance and polymorphic classes, then the destructors should be `virtual`, and then you don't need any casting at all.

Comment: Maybe they meant `EllipseContainer[i]` instead of `Ellipse[i]`.

Comment: And not knowing who "they" are or what "they" mean with `Ellipse[i]`, or even any code except what little you show us, I am *assuming* they mean an array or vector of  pointers to some class that inherits from `Circle`.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question to whoever gave you that code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what they mean with Ellipse[i]

That is probably a mistake because that's ill-formed if `Ellipse` is a type. They probably intended `EllipseContainer[i]`, where `EllipseContainer` is presumably `std::vector<Ellipse*>`.

Also, the double cast is a bit confusing. This would be simpler:

```
delete dynamic_cast<Circle*>(EllipseContainer[i]);
```

Note that if `EllipseContainer[i]` doesn't point to a `Circle`, then this deletes nothing.

---

It's usually a better design to make the destructor of the base virtual, so that no casting is needed to delete a base pointer.

---

About object oriented design: `Ellipse` is probably a bad (public) base for a `Circle` since the classes have potentially conflicting invariants. For example, let's say `Ellipse` has function `set_x_radius()`. The invariant of `Ellipse` says that calling the function would not change the value of `get_y_radius()`. However, the invariant of `Circle` would say that it does change. A derived class should not break invariants of its public bases.

Answer (score 2):

Such cast is necessary only if you have a polymorphic class hierarchy (otherwise `dynamic_cast` wouldn't work) without a `virtual` destructor being defined in the base class (if you have a `virtual` destructor in the base class you can destroy derives instances even through base class pointers).

This is extremely unusual, as, once your class is polymorphic, there's no reason not to have a virtual destructor (you already paid for the vtable) - in facts, is generally considered an error to have a polymorphic class hierarchy without a virtual destructor.

Long story short, just make sure all your polymorphic base classes sport a virtual destructor and just do `delete` without particular casts (or even better, *let smart pointers do the `delete` for you*).

> but I don't really understand what they mean with Ellipse[i], do you have any clues?

As other said, they probably meant `Ellipse` as a vector of `Ellipse *` objects (although there would be a name clash with the `Ellipse` type name).